# Perhaps you are running on JRE rather than JDK

Tags: eclipse, maven, appfuse

I made a project by appfuse.The command is:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-light-spring-security-archetype 
-DarchetypeVersion=3.5.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject 
-DarchetypeRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
```

I have build others project by other `appfuse`command. 
I try to run them projects.
I have the same problem like this:

```
  No compiler is provided in this environment.
 Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I checked my Operating Environment,changed the jre to jdk, included eclipse, mvn build runtime Environment.
But it also has the same problem.
I need help.

Comment: Looks like JAVA_HOME system variable is pointing to a jre, rather than a jdk?

Comment: Thanks Stefan,  i have get it. I missing javac.exe in the dir of my jdk1.8.